# Xcode will not link XCTest to the iOSSimulator version

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xctest

So for one of my classes, we are supposed to refactor this project from last quarter that was left in a pretty bad state.

So we are trying to write unit tests for the project, but they used an old version of Xcode, so we had to re-add the XCTest framework to "Link Binary With Libraries".

I accidentally added the MacOSX version of it the first time, and noticed my error. I removed the OS X version from the linker, and added the iPhoneSimulator version to it. It kept giving me the same error. So I removed all XCTest.framework files from the Build Phases, and it gave me an error about OCMock (which is a totally different problem that I'm not concerned about right now), which means it knows it's gone. So I then tried re-adding XCTest.framework to my test target, making sure it was the iOSSimulator version, and it gives me the same error about it being the Mac OS X version. I have tried restarting Xcode and did correctly that I did before but that did not work. Below is the full output from the error.

```
Ld /Users/MY_USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Henry-ayqkhtmgjufxaagawvfjprhgilji/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HenryTests.xctest/HenryTests normal x86_64
cd /Users/MY_USERNAME/Git/JrProj-1415-Mike/Code/iOS/Henry
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk -L/Users/MY_USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Henry-ayqkhtmgjufxaagawvfjprhgilji/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/MY_USERNAME/Git/JrProj-1415-Mike/Code/iOS/Henry -F/Users/MY_USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Henry-ayqkhtmgjufxaagawvfjprhgilji/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/MY_USERNAME/Git/JrProj-1415-Mike/Code/iOS/Henry -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/MY_USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Henry-ayqkhtmgjufxaagawvfjprhgilji/Build/Intermediates/Henry.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HenryTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HenryTests.LinkFileList -bundle_loader /Users/MY_USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Henry-ayqkhtmgjufxaagawvfjprhgilji/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Henry.app/Henry -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework XCTest -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework XCTest -lOCMock -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework Firebase -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/MY_USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Henry-ayqkhtmgjufxaagawvfjprhgilji/Build/Intermediates/Henry.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HenryTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HenryTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/MY_USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Henry-ayqkhtmgjufxaagawvfjprhgilji/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HenryTests.xctest/HenryTests

ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone come across this problem too, pretty much the only solution is to make a new project, and add all the files to that new project. I've talked to some professionals in iOS development, and they could come up with no other solution. I think it has something to do with the project being from a pretty old version of Xcode, and the new XCTest framework being pretty new. Good luck to you if you come across this too.